# Can board square letters and numbers be added to the PGN viewer?

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

I'm not completely familiar with all the squares by heart yet and I think having board square letters and numbers along the files and ranks is a good feature for beginners (who ask most of the questions) to have in the embedded PGN viewer. (For comparison, this is supported on major sites by default on lichess and chess.com.)

Comment: Perhaps not by default, but with an option to turn this feature on and off?

Comment: I found my question was a dupe I missed earlier

Comment: @Glorfindel also I don't think it will hurt to have it always present. The popular sites I listed have it on by default and this site is used more for learning anyway.